# Unable to trigger automatic build of source code from external Git in Azure DevOps Using CI pipeline

Tags: .net, git, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have the .NET Core Project in the External Git Repository. I have the Azure DevOps Build Pipeline created. The Build is successful and artifacts  gets created when I trigger the Build pipeline manually but failing when its automatic trigger with following error:

```
An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\Common\VssHttpMessageHandler.cs:line 258 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds, Boolean useAnonymousAccess) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line 0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds, Boolean useAnonymousAccess) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitConnector.cs:line 145 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line 454 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters, Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2& ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Git\GitSourceProvider.cs:line 369 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\BuildPollingJobExtension.cs:line 98.
```

Attached CI Trigger Configuration screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hi Nagaraj,Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: I already gave the Git Clone URL with  https in Azure Service Connection. Is there any root cause?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Disabling this box “Attempt accessing this Git server from Azure Pipeline” should normalize the trigger behavior.

[image]

Comment: I already gave the Git Clone URL with https in Azure Service Connection. Is there any root cause? –

Comment: @nagaraj  According to a similar issue, the solution of that case is deleting the old service connection and recreate a new one. You could also give it a try in your side. Besides, if you are using any *proxy*, try to disable the proxy and test it again. This will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: If all above are still not work. Could you provide more info so we can try to reproduce it in our side. What's your remote external Git repo? Are you using GitLab or something else?

Comment: I can't provide the GIT URL since it breaks my organization policy. I suspect this cannot be resolved by creating Service connection. Do you think any permission to be provided from GIT?

Comment: Hi Nagaraj, if it's permission related, kindly check **if you are using different account to connect your external repo.** Since for manually build, it's triggered by your own account. For CI build, it's triggered by your build service account. You could use system.debug=true to enable more detail log info for troubleshooting. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Nagaraj, any update on this issue, have you figured it out ?

Comment: Not able to get much progress. I tried re creating git service connection but no luck

Comment: @nagaraj Thanks for your kindly update. Could you add `system.debug=true` to enable more detail log info for troubleshooting.  And then share logs here, check if this help to provide more information for future troubleshooting.

Comment: @  PatrickLu-MSFT: I have updated the detailed exception message in the issue description.

Comment: @nagaraj Find something new, if adding new service connection from the pipeline as the screenshot shows, the CI will be triggered. But if creating the service connection from service connections, the CI won't be triggered. Did you add service connection in the pipeline directly. If not, kindly give a shot. Details please see my update screenshot.

Comment: Besides, what's the result if you try it with a new build pipeline? Which may do the trick.

Comment: any solutions to this?

Comment: @esskar Please see my latest update, it should do the trick.